LinkedIn OAuth returning access_denied
I'm trying to get OAuth via LinkedIn to work in my webapi application. I have Google OAuth working fine, but I'm still getting tripped up on LinkedIn and I'm at a loss as to what the problem is now. I can get to LinkedIn and sign in, it'll hit my callback url (/signin-linkedin) passing code and state query string parameters, that hits my LinkedInAuthProvider classes ReturnEndpoint method, but at that point, if I inspect the LinkedInReturnEndpointContext passed to that method Identity == null, which then ends up causing my RedirectUrl to be called with the query string added error=access_denied. Is there any way to get more information out of this as to where it's failing? There seems to be no other information provided from LinkedIn.
For some context, I had a similar problem with Google for a while until I realized that I'd mixed up my Google secret for auth (I had two apps set up in Google for testing and I had the key from one and the secret from the other). This is not the case, I have checked and double-checked the key and secret from the LinkedIn console and even regenerated a key just to be sure. I also know the way LinkedIn OAuth works had changed fairly recently, for example, I was initially failing because it was sending the wrong scope that apparently were changed at some point, and even though I had the latest Owin.Security.Providers.LinkedIn, it still sent the old scopes.
Here's some code with how this is set up:
In Startup.Auth:
            var linkedInOptions = new LinkedInAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                ClientId = AuthKeys.LinkedInKey,            
                ClientSecret = AuthKeys.LinkedInSecret,     
                CallbackPath = PathString.FromUriComponent(new Uri(Properties.Settings.Default.LinkedInRedirect)),
                Provider = new LinkedInAuthProvider(),
            };
            linkedInOptions.Scope.Clear();
            linkedInOptions.Scope.Add("openid");
            linkedInOptions.Scope.Add("email");
            linkedInOptions.Scope.Add("profile");

            app.UseLinkedInAuthentication(linkedInOptions);

My ChallengeResult
    public class ChallengeResult : IHttpActionResult
    {
        public string LoginProvider { get; set; }
        public HttpRequestMessage Request { get; set; }

        public ChallengeResult(string loginProvider, ApiController controller)
        {
            LoginProvider = loginProvider;
            Request = controller.Request;
        }

        public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
            Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(LoginProvider);
                        
            response.RequestMessage = Request;
            return Task.FromResult(response);
        }
    }

My LinkedInAuthProvider:
    public class LinkedInAuthProvider : ILinkedInAuthenticationProvider
    {
        public void ApplyRedirect(LinkedInApplyRedirectContext context)
        {
            context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri);
        }

        public Task Authenticated(LinkedInAuthenticatedContext context)
        {
            context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("ExternalAccessToken", context.AccessToken));
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }

        public Task ReturnEndpoint(LinkedInReturnEndpointContext context)
        {
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }
    }

Note that ReturnEndpoint gets called but Authenticated never does.
Any thoughts? Also note that I am running locally, if that makes a difference. I actually have it redirect to https://account.example.com:44301/signin-linkedin which I have set to local host in my .hosts file.
EDIT
So poking around and looking at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow?context=linkedin%2Fcontext&tabs=HTTPS1
It seems that there is a whole extra step that LinkedIn needs to do after it comes back from calling https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization and then coming back to my redirect_url, so I thought I should probably try to do that in  ReturnEndpoint. So now I have this to call https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken:
public async Task ReturnEndpoint(LinkedInReturnEndpointContext context)
        {
            // TODO: check for error here...
            var code = context.Request.Query["code"];

            var request = HttpWebRequest.Create("https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken");
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            // this has to match the redirect that was sent before...
            var redirect = context.Request.Uri.GetComponents(UriComponents.Scheme | UriComponents.HostAndPort | UriComponents.Path, UriFormat.Unescaped);

            var form = new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                { "grant_type", "authorization_code" },
                { "code", code },
                { "client_id", AuthKeys.LinkedInKey },
                { "client_secret", AuthKeys.LinkedInSecret },
                { "redirect_uri", redirect }
            };

            var bodyStr = string.Join("&", form.Select(kvp => $"{kvp.Key}={kvp.Value}"));
            var bodyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(bodyStr);
            request.ContentLength = bodyBytes.Length;

            using (var stream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync())
            {
                stream.Write(bodyBytes, 0, bodyBytes.Length);
            }

            try
            {
                var response = request.GetResponse();       
            }
            catch (System.Net.WebException e)
            {
                var message = new StreamReader(e.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
            }
        }

I've tried this various ways, but it seems like it's not sending the body of the POST here. I get a WebException and the message is
{
    "error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "Unable to retrieve access token: appid/redirect uri/code verifier does not match authorization code. Or authorization code expired. Or external member binding exists"
}

And I can't figure out what the problem there is supposed to be either
